# Login e Senha NavBar - Estilo Facebook

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo problemas para conseguir colocar o login e senha e Bottom um seguido do outro o código é esse:

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" method="post">
<div class="um-row _um_row_1 " style="margin: 0 0 30px 0;">
<div class="um-col-131">
<div id="um_field_14_username" class="um-field um-field-text  um-field-username um-field-text um-field-type_text" data-key="username">
<div class="um-field-label">Login e Senha:<br />
<div class="um-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="um-field-area"><input id="username-14" class="um-form-field valid " autocomplete="off" name="username-14" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-validate="unique_username_or_email" data-key="username" /><input id="user_password-14" class="um-form-field valid " name="user_password-14" type="password" value="" placeholder="" data-validate="" data-key="user_password" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="um-col-133">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="um-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<input id="form_id_14" name="form_id" type="hidden" value="14" />
<p class="um_request_name"><label for="um_request_14">Only fill in if you are not human</label> <input id="um_request_14" class="input" autocomplete="off" name="um_request" size="25" type="hidden" value="" /></p>
<input id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" type="hidden" value="1ce67b9a77" /><input name="_wp_http_referer" type="hidden" value="/login/" />
<div class="um-col-alt">
<div class="um-field um-field-c">
<div class="um-field-area"><label class="um-field-checkbox "> <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <span class="um-field-checkbox-option"> Keep me signed in</span> </label></div>
</div>
<div class="um-clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="um-left um-half"><input id="um-submit-btn" class="um-button" type="submit" value="Login" /></div>

</form>
```

Alguém com alguma sugestão??

Imagem de como esta o codigo:
[Tela Login](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdTlSefrkkCYfAD8oQ5t-ZXbf_0kSdl1/view)

o problema é que não consigo colocar ele pra ficar em uma linha só e sem perder a conexão do "banco" na hora de clicar no login

Comment: E como fica com esse código?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdTlSefrkkCYfAD8oQ5t-ZXbf_0kSdl1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: o problema é que não consigo colocar ele pra ficar em uma linha só e sem perder a conexão do "banco" na hora de clicar no login

Comment: Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar toda informação pertinente a ela nela.